# Sending dynamic data to a code block in a viewpage in asp.net mvc 4 ...

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

i was trying to send dynamic data to a session so that on page load a dynamic value will be used by a code block which has a LINQ statement that loads a different data ... i was trying to do all this on the view side without going to the controller.. u can understand it better by going through the code.. it is just an idea i thought to try and not using anywhere ...

```
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Index"    
    Dim vs As New Ve.VeDataSource
    If (Session("dynamicDataToPass") = Nothing) Then
        Dim q = ((From r In vs.aspnet_Roles Order By r.RoleId Select r.RoleName).Skip(1)).FirstOrDefault
        ViewData("q1") = q
    Else
        Dim m As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Session("dynamicDataToPass").ToString)
        Dim q = ((From r In vs.aspnet_Roles Order By r.RoleId Select r.RoleName).Skip(m)).FirstOrDefault
        ViewData("q1") = q
    End If   
    Session("dynamicDataToPass") = Nothing
End Code

<h2>Index</h2>

@ViewData("q1")
<select id="secbox">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#secbox").change(function () {

          var p= $("#secbox").val();
            @Code
                Session("dynamicDataToPass") = Nothing
                Session("dynamicDataToPass") = //something here to set the val to session
            End Code
            window.location.reload();
        });
    });

</script>
```

My question is how to assign jquery value to session and i am not sure if it is possible or not .. its just a try.. thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, as you have decided to use MVC as your development design pattern views should contain mostly visual markup code (Html, CSS, JavaScript).  Your logic should be compiled in your controller and return a model with the information needed to render your view.

In your case, a solution would be to post the value of the select box to an action in your controller and set the value of the session

View

```
$.post(/Save, {id : $("#secbox").val()}, function()
{
   // DO SOMETHING
});
```

Action

```
 [HttpPost] 
 public ActionResult Save(int id)
 {
   Session("dynamicDataToPass") =  id

   return view();

  }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: this is what i do normally .. insted of using controller i want to send the value to session and then reload the page using javascript ... this is just a test and i am not using it anywhere ...

Comment: Does my initial response answer your question? You may want to consider using jquery template or knockout.js to update the view